# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth.accountallauth'

Tags: python, django

I've a app name cz.

**Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\ashis\PycharmProjects\ChatZone\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\ashis\PycharmProjects\ChatZone\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\ashis\PycharmProjects\ChatZone\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\ashis\PycharmProjects\ChatZone\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\ashis\PycharmProjects\ChatZone\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "C:\Users\ashis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth.accountallauth'
```

This is my settings.py file:

```
from pathlib import Path

from django.template.backends import django
import os
import allauth

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []



INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'cz',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account'
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ChatZone.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ChatZone.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
 'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
 )

SITE_ID = 1
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        }
    }
}
```

My urls.py for the project ChatZone:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
import allauth

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='cz/index.html')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('cz/',include('cz.urls')),
]
```

I've tried many approach to solve this problem but I don't know how to solve it. I've searched everywhere but I can't find this module in my code. How can I tackle these kinds of problems in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've missed a comma. Very common typo:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'cz',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account' # no comma here
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
]
```

So you want:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'cz',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account', # comma added
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can specify which version of python your web app uses -3.7, 3.8. choose a python version that you have installed the package, be sure the same.

*pip 3.8 install --user allauth*

after that create a virtualenv and virtualenv's using the python version and then
 *pip install allauth*